# How to make mouseover changing button?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a mouseover changing button like the following:
https://www.kickstarter.com/discover?ref=nav

When you mouse over "Technology" for example, it animates/scrolls to different text. A CSS**3**/HTML5 solution is ideal, unless javascript is required.

Comment: To do animation you'll need some javascript.  You could use jQuery's animate function.

Comment: @raduation that's not true. CSS has `animation` and `transition.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write your own code.. Anyway, here is a jsfiddle with a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/kya6skp1/

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="text main">Text 1</div>
    <div class="text secondary">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
    transition: top 300ms linear;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.text.main {
    top: 0;
}
.wrap:hover .text.main {
    top: -100%;
}
.text.secondary {
    top: 100%;
}
.wrap:hover .text.secondary {
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in CSS or JavaScript, however using CSS will only allow you to change the style, the scrolling part you want requires JavaScript. I'll tell you how to do it in both languages though. Keep in mind that it shouldn't make up an important part of your code, because if you plan to put the page on the web, it won't work for tablet/mobile phones, which have no mouse. Bu the way, I'm assuming your buttons are just button type inputs. Anyways...

CSS:

```
<style>
    #theIDOfMyInput 
    {
        //This is the default style
    }
    #theIDOfMyInput:hover
    {
        //This is the style that appears when your mouse is over the button
    }
</style>
```

JavaScript

In the tag declaring your input, write:

```
<input type="button" onMouseOver="MyFunction()">
```

Then add a function called MyFunction() to the script and make it affect the button, probably using the DOM to change it's innerHTML.

Comment: You can do the "scrolling part" que with css3, you don't need js. Also the OP asks for a non-js solution.. There is a simple approach in my answer if you want to check it out..